# How can I change the outliner Restriction Toggles with Python?

Tags: python, interface, outliner

I'd like to be able to change the restriction toggles (filters) that are displayed on the right of the outliner, similar to this :

[image]

But with the Python API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These restriction toggles are attributes of the [SpaceOutliner](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SpaceOutliner.html) class which is a child class of [Space](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Space.html).

Each [Area](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html) in the [Screen](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Screen.html) holds one or more Space(s). Thankfully the Outliner area only holds one.

```
import bpy

# Fetch the first outliner area in the screen
# Will throw error if workspace doesn't contain any outliner editor.
outliner_area = next(a for a in bpy.context.screen.areas if a.type == "OUTLINER")

space = outliner_area.spaces[0]
space.show_restrict_column_enable = True  # Collection exclusion (Checkbox icon)
space.show_restrict_column_select = True  # Selection state (Cursor icon)
space.show_restrict_column_hide = True  # Local visibility (Eye icon)
space.show_restrict_column_viewport = True  # Global visibility (Monitor icon)
space.show_restrict_column_render = True  # Render visibility (Camera icon)
space.show_restrict_column_holdout = True  # Holdout
space.show_restrict_column_indirect_only = True  # Indirect only
```

[image]